# Visual F# Windows form closing after showing

Tags: winforms, f#

Good Day,

I have just started learning visual F#, and it looks surprisingly fun to do. For my first project I got my hands dirty by immediately make a windows form to download info from a page and display it in a RichTextBox on the form. Problem is, once the form shows and information is downloaded, it immediately closes. How do I keep my masterpiece open for viewing? Any advice?

I have 2 Files currently:

- Program.fs
- Script1.fs

Program.fs is supposed to "create" the form, where Script1.fs is merely the entrypoint for the application.

```
Program.fs

namespace Program1
    open System.Windows.Forms

    module public HelloWorld =
        let form = new Form(Visible = true, TopMost = true, Text = "Welcome to F#")

        let textB = new RichTextBox(Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Text = "Initial Text")
        form.Controls.Add textB

        open System.IO
        open System.Net

        /// Get the contents of the URL via a web request
        let http (url: string) =
         let req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
         let resp = req.GetResponse()
         let stream = resp.GetResponseStream()
         let reader = new StreamReader(stream)
         let html = reader.ReadToEnd()
         resp.Close()
         html
        textB.Text <- http "http://www.google.com"
```

Script1.fs

```
open Program1

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv= 
        printfn "Running F# App"
        HelloWorld.form.Show();
        0
```

I need to reiterate, I  started with F#. This is my first application I wrote. How do I keep the form open?

Comment: My guess is that the entrypoint hits it's return value because I do not have the equivalent of `Console.Readline()` from C# after showing my form.

Comment: The key to this is the Windows Message Loop - read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows for background information :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `Application.Run` and pass your form object into it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx

This will create a message loop, and keep your application alive until the form is closed.

```
open Program1

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv= 
    printfn "Running F# App"
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(HelloWorld.form)
    0
```

Comment: Thanks. I posted my answer too but got nailed with downvotes, Ain't nobody got rep for that. Always helps when someone more-experienced helps out rather

Comment: You kinda almost had the right idea with your answer. You were using `Console.ReadLine` as a **blocking method** - a method which effectively stops your program ending prematurely. `Application.Run` is also a blocking method, but is designed specifically for running windows forms applications. In this case it blocks until it receives a close signal - and only then your program ends.

Comment: Makes sense. To be square however, in c# I mostly work with compiled dll Assemblies and asp.net/mvc and nearly never see any front-end development. Learned two things at once . thanks

Comment: @Noobgrammer The other issue is that in most C# projects, this particular bit of the program is pre-generated for you, so you wouldn't really have any cause to learn how to do it.